# Android splash screen keeps crashing on some devices only

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am almost new to Android. I add splash screen to the app with code from this site as follows:

1. creating drawable file for splash
2. creating theme in styles for splash
3. applying the theme on home screen

styles.xml

```
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
    </style>
```

splash_background.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/splash"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/ib_logo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
</xml>
```

applying the the splash them on home screan in Android Manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".main.MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

That works fine on my test devices and even on the versions of the app I install from play store and works on all emulators but I get crash reports from users on different Android versions and different mobile makers with this part of the crash report:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage/com.mypackage.main.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.mypackage:drawable/splash_background with resource ID #0x7f0800d7
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2974)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.mypackage:drawable/splash_background with resource ID #0x7f0800d7
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800d7
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:870)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:680)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:892)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:834)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:454)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:411)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachToWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:613)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:340)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:105)
at com.mypackage.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:35)
at com.mypackage.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:56)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1221)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateSpr(DrawableInflater.java:253)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:138)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1322)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1311)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:284)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:194)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:146)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1322)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1281)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:857)
... 27 more
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.mypackage:drawable/splash_background with resource ID #0x7f0800d7
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800d7
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:870)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:680)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:892)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:834)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:454)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:411)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachToWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:613)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:340)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:105)
at com.mypackage.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:35)
at com.mypackage.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:56)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1221)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateSpr(DrawableInflater.java:253)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:138)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1322)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1311)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:284)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:194)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:146)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1322)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1281)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:857)
... 27 more
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800d7
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:870)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:680)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:892)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:834)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:454)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:411)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachToWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:613)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:340)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:105)
at com.mypackage.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:35)
at com.mypackage.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:56)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1221)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateSpr(DrawableInflater.java:253)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:138)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1322)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1311)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:284)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:194)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:146)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1322)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1281)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:857)
... 27 more
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateSpr(DrawableInflater.java:253)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:138)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1322)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1311)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:284)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:194)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:146)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1322)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1281)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:857)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:680)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:892)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:834)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:454)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:411)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachToWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:613)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:340)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:105)
at com.mypackage.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:35)
at com.mypackage.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:56)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1221)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

why do I get resource not found for the splash xml file even it exists.

This is the mobile device I got this crash report on:

```
Samsung Galaxy J7 Core SM-J701F specifications:

    – 5.5 Inch (720 x 1280 pixels (HD)) Super AMOLED capacitive touchscreen, Scratch Resistant (2.5D Curved Glass)
    – 1.6 GHz Octa Core Exynos (7870) CPU with Mali T830 GPU.
    – 2 GB RAM and 16 GB internal storage.

Oct 16, 2017
Samsung Galaxy J7 Core SM-J701F Specifications - GSM-specs.com
https://www.gsm-specs.com/specifications/samsung-galaxy-j7-core-sm-j701f/
```

This is my res folder and all files exists in the "drawable" folder.

[image]

Comment: where is your `@drawable/splash` ??

Comment: @KrishnaSharma splash.xml, splash_background.xml, and the ib_logo.png image all in the "drawable" folder only not in any other folders.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: 
If the crashes are from older devices then its because you are using vector drawables.
Vector files need to be referenced with `android:srcCompat` rather than `android:src` for backward compatibility.

**Old Answer: (May work for some)**
This could be happening because you have different `drawable` folders for different Android versions and you did not include your `splash_background` drawable in your `drawable` folder. Go to your `res` folder in your app module, it might look like this:

[image]

Now make sure that your background is in `drawable` folder as well and you are good to go.

Comment: I update the question. I have all files in the "drawable" folder but not in the drawable-xxxx folders. is that what you mean

Comment: If you have all files in `drawable` folder then you are doing it right, let me take a look at it again.

Comment: I updated the question for the device information. It is new and good hardware.

Comment: I added more from the crash report it may help

Comment: @daliaessam where is you `@drawable/splash` located? is it in mipmap folder or drawable?

Comment: all three files, the two xml and the .png in the "drawable" folder only.

Comment: @daliaessam are you using the latest version of build tools and gradle?

Comment: Yes using the latest of everything. as I said all my devices and emulators do not have this problem, only I get this report from some users different devices even newest mobiles.